# In this code string is not reading for first time

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    int i , j = 0;
    scanf("%d" , &i);
    while(i--)
    {
        gets(str);
        printf("%s\n" , str);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

In this code string is not reading for the first time..code looks alright but not able to figure out problem.

Comment: Don't use `gets()` use `fgets()`, `gets()` is dangerous and deprecated. Also you are one more of those who don't know how `scanf()` should be used.

Comment: i have used scanf("%[^\n]s" , str); in place of gets ...but same problem persists..

Comment: `scanf("%d" , &i);` still leaving newline.

Comment: anyway fgets is used for reading from file ... i have to read from console

Comment: ｔｒｙ`scanf(" %49[^\n]" , str);` //note: The beginning of the space characters are ignored.

Comment: not working scanf(" %49[^\n]" , str); garbage value of str is coming

Comment: it's working for me. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/JDvh2l)

Comment: @DivakarSunny , Did you add a space between `"` and `%49[^\n]` when using `scanf(" %49[^\n]" , str);`?

Answer (score 3):

It is because after you input a number for the `scanf`, you press the enter key. This character is not consumed by the `scanf` and stays in the standard input buffer.

In the first iteration, `gets` reads the newline character left by the scanf and does not wait for input.

To fix it, change

```
scanf("%d" , &i);
```

To

```
scanf("%d%*c" , &i);
```

The `%*c` instructs `scanf` to scan a character and discard it. In your case, it will scan the newline character and discard it.

Also, avoid using `gets` as [it is dangerous](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) because it does not prevent [buffer overruns](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Instead, use the [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) function:

```
fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
```